# How to read contents of uploaded files in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I want to read the text of an uploaded file. The uploaded file is a .txt file. For some reason `contents` is always a blank string.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    string contents = new StreamReader(upload.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

The html:

```
<form action="/Document/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input class="" accept=".txt" type="file" name="uf" required />
</form>
```

Comment: You need to read the contents of the `HttpPostedFileBase` property in your `UploadViewModel` model

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I tried that method and it didnt work either.

Comment: We probably need a bit more to give you any kind of meaningful help. Just posting the controller code doesn't really help see what the problem is. For instance, are you uploading this with a normal POST? If so, does your form have the correct enctype? If you're uploading via AJAX, how?

Comment: Yes, it is using a normal POST request. The enctype I am using is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Your file input is named `name="uf"` - That does not match your `HttpPostedFileBase upload` parameter and the value of `upload` will always be `null`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make sure that the input stream is reset to the first bit. I would normally read the file into a memory stream, first:

```cs
string contents = string.Empty;

using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    upload.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;

    contents = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Otherwise, simply resetting the index might be enough:

```cs
upload.InputStream.Position = 0;

string contents = new StreamReader(upload.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```